# Text Slider built with CSS animation not showing on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my first portfolio website and wanted to add a text slider on the homepage that would cycle through a list.

Published draft is here: https://ryanpearson.website/

On desktop the list cycles through fine. When I use Chrome devtools to inspect and change screen size down to mobile, the list cycles fine. However, when I load the page on an actual cell phone or tablet, instead of using responsive sizing w/ devtools, the slider portion of this text disappears. I cant figure out why.

I thought maybe it was the elements needing a defined height, or that some of my animation isn't supported. . . but the phone i'm using is an iPHone XS, and the newest iPad.

HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="container-banner-text">
        <span class="banner-text">Hi, I'm Ryan and I 
          <br>
          <div class="content-slider">
              <div class="slider">
                <div class="mask">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="anim1">
                      <div class="quote">am a jr web dev.</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="anim2">
                      <div class="quote">love learning.</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="anim3">
                      <div class="quote">love organization.</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="anim4">
                      <div class="quote">love beautiful design.</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="anim5">
                      <div class="quote">love efficiency.</div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </span>
      </div>

.container-banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top:40%; 
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

.banner-text {
  color: rgba(var(--white), 1);
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif ;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin:auto;
}

/* text carousel */

.slider {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 45vh;
}

.slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  background: rgba(var(--white), 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(var(--red),1), rgba(var(--orange),1),rgba(var(--gold),1)); 
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: text ;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.slider li.anim1 {
  animation: cycle 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim2 {
  animation: cycle2 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim3 {
  animation: cycle3 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim4 {
  animation: cycle4 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider li.anim5 {
  animation: cycle5 15s linear infinite;
}

.slider:hover li {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes cycle {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  4% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  16% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  21% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  50% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  92% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  96% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes cycle2 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  16% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  36% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  41% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes cycle3 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  44% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  56% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  61% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes cycle4 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  56% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  64% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  81% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes cycle5 {
  0% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  76% {
    top: -325px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  84% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  96% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 325px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code I noticed the in some cases a display: none is being added to the slider `<div class="container-banner-text" style="display: none;">`

Comment: Thanks @ion for looking at this. The site is built on one page and uses javascript to toggle between sections and uses functions to change sections from display:none to display: inline-flex. So I think that is what you are seeing, and it is working as intended. Plus, I'm able to see the slider text on all screen sizes on my laptop. Just not while using my actual phone. So I think it's something to do with how my phone renders websites vs my laptop.

Comment: Turned out that the issue was that I had the slider text wrapped in a div when it didn't need to be. I removed the div and just used the styles on the <li> and now it's visible. It's interesting that this issue only affected Apple mobile devices (iphone and iPad) and not android or desktop